# JSP page is not rendering properly in spring boot application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using twitter bootstrap for my UI , so for the JSP file to render correctly resource files like css,fonts,images,js,less,scss are required in the project . so i added them in src/main/webapp/resources folder . I have my JSP pages in  src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp folder. 
In application.properties i have specified as follows:

```
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

while running the application i was able to view the jsp page but it is not displayed properly like text fields at one place , button some other place . 
I think the reason is because the JSP is not taking the files i have given in resources folder . This is how i am referencing the resources in JSP page

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script 
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css"> 
</style>
<script>
```

the problem is with improper page rendering . can you please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you've put them to:

```
src/main/webapp/resources
```

Then the correct URL to them in the template would probably be:

```
/resources/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

So, to keep the existing URLs you need to move the static resources up one level, to:

```
src/main/webapp/
```

...getting rid of /resources subdirectory all together.

Answer (score 2):

The way we solved this was fairly easy.  Create a addResourceHandlers in your config.  File would look something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

      registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");

    }

}
```